# How to count unique users in file log?

Tags: erlang

Given a txt log file, which is in the form:

```
USER_A timestamp1 otherstuff
USER_B timestamp2 otherstuff
USER_C timestamp3 otherstuff
USER_A timestamp4 otherstuff
USER_A timestamp5 otherstuff
USER_C timestamp6 otherstuff
USER_B timestamp7 otherstuff
```

How would you count the number of different unique users in erlang? I was thinking about reading the file line by line and using proplists module. Each user will be a key, with a value that will be the number of occurrences. Once the file is read, I call:

```
length(proplists:get_keys(List)).
```

Is this the correct way to achieve my result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also use the sets module for this since it is both fast and as a set contains no duplicates.

The following code should do the job:

```
{ok,Bin} = file:read_file("test"),
List = binary_to_list(Bin),
Usernames = [hd(string:tokens(X," ")) || X <- string:tokens(List,[$\n])],
sets:size(sets:from_list(Usernames)).
```

Edit: I deleted the one-liner since it didn't add any value

Comment: Note that this will hold the entire file in memory. It may be better from a memory perspective to read one line at a time from the file and add the username to the set, for example in a recursive function.

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be more appropriate to use a set from the [`sets`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/sets.html) module to store the usernames and then use [`sets:size/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/sets.html#size-1).

Answer (score 1):

Log files are often large so consider working with it one line at a time in a recursive function:

```
% Count the number of distinct users in the file named Filename                        
count_users(Filename) ->
    {ok, File} = file:open(Filename, [read, raw, read_ahead]),
    Usernames = usernames(File, sets:new()),
    file:close(File),
    sets:size(Usernames).

% Add all users in File, from the current file pointer position and forward,
% to Set.
% Side-effects: File is read and the file pointer is moved to the end.          
usernames(File, Set) ->
    case file:read_line(File) of
        {ok, Line} ->
            Username = hd(string:tokens(Line, " ")),
            usernames(File, sets:add_element(Username, Set));
        eof ->
            Set
    end.
```

You just call it like this: `count_users("logfile")`.

Note that `usernames/2` must be [tail recursive](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion#length-tail-recursion) for this to work efficiently. Otherwise it would just consume even more memory.